# NHibernate Criteria query on in-memory collection of entities

Tags: linq, nhibernate, hql, nhibernate-criteria

I would like to apply a Criteria query to an in-memory collection
of entities, instead of on the database. Is this possible?
To have Criteria API work like LINQ? Or alternatively, convert
Criteria query to LINQ query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can use Criteria to query against an in-memory collection and come to think about it it doesn't seem to make much sense. If I'm understanding everything correctly you've already queried against your database. I'd suggest to either tune your original query (whichever method you choose) to include all of your filters. Or you could use LINQ (as you suggested) to refine your results.

Also, what's your reasoning for wanting to query from memory?

Comment: Thanks, Mike. Here is the scenario: I run a query against the database using Criteria, and cache the query results (entity ids).

Comment: Now, I update an entity that was in my original query result. Instead of evicting the cached query, I want to re-run the query in memory, and update the cached query.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're rolling your own caching mechanism. I would highly recommend checking out NHibernate's 2nd level cache. It handles many complex scenarios gracefully such as invalidating query results on updates to the underlying tables.

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/24/nhibernate-2nd-level-cache.aspx

Comment: Thanks, James. I am aware of the 2nd level cache. I want to make a smarter version, that does a little more work to avoid invalidating the queries.

Comment: Have you considered/investigated integrating with the 2nd level cache? Would creating your own ICacheProvider that wrapped an existing one provide you with sufficient control? Just a thought rather than essentially re-implementing the entire feature set of the 2nd level cache...